# I want to add this content to a fancybox pop up, trying to embed div in fancybox

Tags: popup, fancybox

I have this link to a chess game but instead of it just displaying on the page id like it to be in a pop up. iv got videos, images, websites ext to pop up but having trouble with this. iv tried using a hidden div but couldnt get it to work.

I would much appreciate it if anyone could help.

thanks in advance

stephen

site with game i want to embed.

http://www.freegaming.de/onlinegames/Casino-|-Card-|-Board-Games/Classic-Chess-Game.html

Answer (score 0):

I Read about Fancybox Usage in its home page...
Make sure You Have latest fancybox, folder layout like this...
It's a quick solution :) but it works!

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

`<title>My Title</title>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#various4").fancybox({
            'padding'           : 0,
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        });
    });
</script>
```

`</head>`

`<body>`

`<a id="various4" href="http://www.freegaming.de/components/flash//classic chess.swf">Swf</a>`

`</body>`

`</html>`

I think now it's the asked solution....

Comment: This would hide the link and cause it to be clicked on load, I don't think that is what he wants